# UITableView : Strange checkmark accessory type behavior

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

A gif to introduce my problem :

[image]

In my `UITableView` I set a checkmark accessory type but a white background appears instead of displaying the checkmark of the cell. The checkmark is here, but why do I have this white background ?

The `tint color` of my cell is set to `white`, changing it just change the color of the checkmark and the background is **still here**.

My code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CheckTableViewCell {
        if cell.titleLabel.text != "" {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CheckTableViewCell {
            cell.setUp(withTitle: dataSource[indexPath.row].title)
            return cell
        }
        return CheckTableViewCell()
}

func setUp(withTitle title : String){
    self.titleLabel.text = title
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Show your `cellForRowAt` method.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set both `cell content's View` and `UITableView` **background color** to pink in StoryBoard to make it works.